# KFold - LogLoss in training set and validation set for Decision Tree

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

I'm working on an binary classifier using decision tree. The question is asking for , **using cross-validation with 10 splits, to calculate the LogLoss at the training set and validation set.**

This is **the code:**

```
model = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_depth=None)
cv = KFold(n_splits=10, shuffle=False)

scores = cross_val_score(model, x, y, scoring='neg_log_loss', cv=cv, n_jobs=-1)
# force scores to be positive
scores = absolute(scores)
scores.mean()
```

This is **the output** [scores.mean()] :

```
3.1660909289719665
```

**> How can I calculate the training set and the validation of Kfold? And

> this output, would be which one?**

The **4 Options** are: 8 and 6 / 0 and 3 / 0 and 0 / LogLoss does not make sense here .

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

`cross_val_score` returns only the validation scores. So, the mean you calculated is the mean of validation splits/sets. To find the training score, you may use [`cross_validate`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_validate), get 10 training scores and average them.

Comment: using of course the option `return_train_score=True`